# Always in loading state microsoft bizspark azure

Tags: azure

After azure subscription from biz spark  when i login from my parent account then its always in loading state. my child accounts working fine now can any one tell me what is the issue here is the screen shot.[image]

Comment: Why is this tagged with `azure` tag?

Comment: because this is azure subscription issue.

Comment: No it is not! It is not Azure Portal as far as I can tell.

Comment: its bizspark u can suggest me what is the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea, sorry! Can you check developer console? May be some JavaScript related error preventing the site to load properly. In any case, I don't think it is the right forum for this as the issue you're facing is not related to programming.